# Flutter Expanded Single Scroll View cause Widget to overlap on other widget

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, scrollable

I have a UI that wanted to just allow the list tile part to be scrollable where I am using Expanded and SingleChildScrollView in a Column to achieve this. But when I scroll the ListTile border will appear on the other widget. How should I get rid of this?

[image]

Below is my sample code:

```
Padding(
padding:
    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
child: Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: _selectedDate,
        builder: (context, value, child) {
          return TableCalendar(
              focusedDay: _selectedDate.value,
              firstDay: DateTime(1900),
              lastDay: DateTime(2100),
              calendarFormat: CalendarFormat.week,
              calendarStyle: const CalendarStyle(
                  defaultTextStyle:
                      TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
              headerStyle: const HeaderStyle(
                  formatButtonVisible: false,
                  titleCentered: true,
                  titleTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                  headerPadding: EdgeInsets.zero),
              calendarBuilders: CalendarBuilders(
        }),
    Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
        child: Text('data',
            style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))),
    const Text('Location Updates',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
    Expanded(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
               mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
               children: [
                  for (var L in _empLog.value) logListTile(L)
               ],
             ),
     ))
  ],
)),
```

Comment: remove the expanded widget and try

Comment: if i remove the expanded widget, i will get the overflow error